# How do multiple parameters of the parLapply function correspond to each list?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, arguments

I have a dataframe that I want to do, and each column has a different quantile. How do you pass each quantile as a parameter?

```
parLapply(cl,list(c(1:100),c(2:78)), fun = cut, breaks = c(0,2,10,30,50,100))
```

The first code can be implemented.

```
parLapply(cl,list(c(1:100),c(2:78)), fun = cut, breaks = list(c(0,2,100),c(0,5,7,999)))
```

The second code can not be implemented.

The second code gives an error：

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: (serial) object cannot be forced to 
  change to 'double' type.
```